# Canon printer won't print some black part

Tags: 12.04, printing, canon

I have a Canon i560 installed on an ubuntu 12.04. When I print the print test page, the "ubuntu" brand name which is black and the black circles don't appear. But the black text in the lower part and the black frame does appear. I can supply a scanned image of the printed sheet if needed (I cannot upload it because I'm a new user...)

When I print from acrobat reader or from google chrome, the resulting page miss black text (some text appear, other won't). Printing from LibreOffice or Firefox work well. The configuration of the printer should be ok since I'm able to print correctly from LibreOffice and firefox. I configured the printer in CMYK mode.

Is it a bug related to ubuntu 12.04 (I never had any problem with previous version but I'm not sure the problem appeared with the upgrade to 12.04) or did I miss something ? If it's a bug, in which package do I have to report it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a couple of things but the fact it prints well in Libre Office and Firefox would probably eliminate any bugs in 12.04 as being the cause as it only occurs in acrobat.

Am I correct in saying that the i560 has 2 black cartridges in the print head?  I know it sounds obvious but do they both have ink or have you checked them for blockages?

If you check all above and are still having issues then you should try printing the test page in **RGB mode**.  The last thing to try is to print the test page in Grayscale rather than color.

Comment: My i560 printer only have one black cartridge (and 3 cartridges for color). I also cleaned the print head in rubbing alcohol. My printer print correctly in windows.

I tried to print the test page in all different color mode:
Greyscale : printing is ok, all test circles appear (in greyscale of course).
RGB : wrong colors, the black circles appears in a very light brown
CMY : good colors, the black circles appears in a very light brown
KCMY or CMYK : good colors, no black circles.